# Is there a cleaner way of getting current URL in both client and server side in isomorphic react apps?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am developing an app based in [this](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example) React Redux boilerplate. 
In one component I need to get the current URL when component is mounted in order to generate a shareable URL for social media. Than component is being accesible from dynamically generated URLs with React Router. In client side I wouldn't have any problem by getting it through javascript `document` object but the problem lies server side.

I thought about making available in the Redux store the Node.js environment data kept in this `config.js` file, where hostname is kept

```
// Node.js environment file config.js    
require('babel-polyfill');

const environment = { 
  development: {
    isProduction: false
  },  
  production: {
    isProduction: true
  }
}[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'];

module.exports = Object.assign({
  host: process.env.HOST || 'localhost',
  port: process.env.PORT,
  apiHost: process.env.APIHOST || 'localhost',
  apiPort: process.env.APIPORT
}, environment);
```

and with the `location` object of React Router set as props in the component get the pathname and fully construct the URL.

What I have done is to create a simple reducer with an initial state to keep the Node.js config enviroment data and just the default action to include in my `combineReducers` function with the other app reducers.

```
const initialState = { 
  config: {}
};

export default function config(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

And then I injected the Node.js object with the environment data in the creation of the store, as initial state data, in my `server.js` file.

```
import config from './config';
...
const store = createStore(memoryHistory, client, {config});
...
```

Thus I have available the hostname and I am able in the component to construct its full url both client and server side through Redux store.

But, is there any simpler / cleanest way? I am afraid I might be overkilling it or creating any security issue to my app.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue when attempting to use Helmet server-side.  I passed in the request as a prop to my main `<App>` component and then use either that request object (server-side) or the window object (client-side).

**App.js**

```
render() {

    // Get full url from client or server
    let fullURL = ''
    if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
        fullURL = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + this.props.location.pathname
    }else if(this.props.serverRequest){
        fullURL = this.props.serverRequest.headers.host + '/' + this.props.location.pathname
    }

    const urlTag = fullURL === '' ? null : <meta property="og:url" content={fullURL} />
    const linkTag = fullURL === '' ? null : <link rel="canonical" href={fullURL} />

    const helmet = this.props.siteInfo.site
        ? <Helmet>
            <title>{this.props.siteInfo.site.title}</title>
            <meta property="twitter:title" content={this.props.siteInfo.site.title} />
            {urlTag}
            {linkTag}
            <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
          </Helmet>
        : null

    return (
        <div>
            {helmet}
            <Notices />
            <div className="body">
                <Header />
                <Body />
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

**server.js**

```
const markup = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
            <App serverRequest={req} />
        </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
)

const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic()
```

Is this "proper" or "best practice"?  No idea, but it works well and is easy to follow :)